# Update missing values in a column using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe df with two of the columns being 'city' and 'zip_code':

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'city': ['Cambridge','Washington','Miami','Cambridge','Miami',
'Washington'], 'zip_code': ['12345','67891','23457','','','']})
```

As shown above, a particular city contains zip code in one of the rows, but the zip_code is missing for the same city in some other row. I want to fill those missing values based on the zip_code values of that city in some other row. Basically, wherever there is a missing zip_code, it checks zip_code for that city in other rows, and if found, fills the value for zip_code.If not found, fills 'NA'.

How do I accomplish this task using pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go for:

```
import numpy as np

df['zip_code'] = df.replace(r'', np.nan).groupby('city')['zip_code'].fillna(method='ffill').fillna(method='bfill')

>>> df
         city zip_code
0   Cambridge    12345
1  Washington    67891
2       Miami    23457
3   Cambridge    12345
4       Miami    23457
5  Washington    67891
```

Comment: TypeError: cannot use label indexing with a null key

Comment: This answer is better than EdChum's as it doesn't give an error on cases where you have cities with different zip_codes. It just chooses the first one.

Comment: @JoãoAlmeida `drop_duplicates` will take the first duplicate so the behaviour should be the same as this answer

Comment: @EdChum only if the entire row is a duplicate, I was talking about having one city with two different zip codes. 
For instance: 
       Miami    23357
       Miami    23457

This would only happen with incorrect data, but could happen

Comment: @JoãoAlmeida you can pass `subset='city'` param to `drop_duplicates` which would then take the first entry

Answer (score 1):

You can check the string length using `str.len` and for those rows, filter the main df to those with valid zip_codes, set the index to those and call `map` on the 'city' column which will perform the lookup and fill those values:

```
In [255]:
df.loc[df['zip_code'].str.len() == 0, 'zip_code'] = df['city'].map(df[df['zip_code'].str.len() == 5].set_index('city')['zip_code'])
df

Out[255]:
         city zip_code
0   Cambridge    12345
1  Washington    67891
2       Miami    23457
3   Cambridge    12345
4       Miami    23457
5  Washington    67891
```

If your real data has lots of repeating values then you'll need to additionally call `drop_duplicates` first:

```
df.loc[df['zip_code'].str.len() == 0, 'zip_code'] = df['city'].map(df[df['zip_code'].str.len() == 5].drop_duplicates(subset='city').set_index('city')['zip_code'])
```

The reason you need to do this is because it'll raise an error if there are duplicate index entries

Comment: AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas

Comment: This means you may have `NaN` values rather than blank string, if so you can replace these first `df['zip_code'] = df['zip_code'].fillna('')` then the code should work

Comment: What is the `dtype` for that column? Is it numeric or is it `str`? In your question the zip_codes are string if your real data is not then you need to post a representative example in your question

Comment: Well then your actual question bears little resemblance to your posted sample df then which basically wastes the community's time. Basically you can do this: `df.loc[df['zip_code'].isnull(), 'zip_code'] = df['city'].map(df[df['zip_code'].notnull()].drop_duplicates(subset='city').set_index('city')['zip_code'])`

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to first create a dictonary that maps from the city to the zip code. You can create this dictionary from the one DataFrame.

And then you use that dictionary to fill in all missing zip code values.